# layout visual issues from vertical to landscape orientation on smartphones

Tags: android, html, css, responsive-design, screen-orientation

I am experimenting some visual issues on samsung smartphones with android when I turn the device in landscape orientation from the vertical orientation, viewing a layout I am writing for a website of mine.

In a case the green buttons don't respect their height parameters so the buttons become too long in height, loosing the shape of a circle, in another case the last button looses the image that contains and the button became flat, with an height of some pixels but a correct width. The other buttons are rendered correctly.

I don't observe these kind of issues using iOS devices.

I can't find the cause, need to fit this responsive bug, please.

No problems are reported using Online emulators.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was lying into the follow code of one of the CSSes:

```
input.menubtn {
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
}
```

I don'tknow why but with this kind of code android on samsnug handle the reported issuse but using the following code:

```
input.menubtn {
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
}
```

I solved the problem.